# List of netfilter modules for which I can leave out the -m option and other implied information

Tags: iptables

Rules in `iptables`/`ip6tables` can sometimes become a bit verbose to read. I am looking for a list of information that I can skip from `iptables`/`ip6tables` that I write.

#### Examples:

- if you say `-s 1.2.3.4` it implies `--mask 255.255.255.255`, i.e. it matches only the exact IPv4 address. Similar stuff exists in the IPv6 realm.
- if you say `-p tcp --dport http` this implies `-m tcp`, the same can be done for the `udp` module, i.e. `--dport` and `--sport` imply the respective module as long the protocol in `-p` matches.

Rationale: The number of implied data for a rule should be finite, which means this isn't an open-ended question, which I had pondered before typing it up.

NB: you can see what's implied for the rules you write by comparing your input with the output if `iptables-save`/`ip6tables-save`. Alas, the problem is that I cannot write up every possible rule, so I am looking for a list or specifically **documentation** outlining what data is implied.